# Как записать результат ajax в переменную?

Tags: jquery, ajax

Делаю так:

```
function test(){
    let result = false;
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            method: 'GET',
            data: {id : id},
            success: function() {
                result = true;
            }
        });

      return result;
}
```

Всегда возвращает false...

Comment: Потому что обработчик `success` будет вызван когда-нибудь в будущем, когда ответит сервер, а `result` будет возвращён прямо сейчас, когда он равен `false`. Возвращайте promise.

Comment: Блин!
Спасибо!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ajax-запрос асинхронный, поэтому результат его выполнения появится позже, после того, как произойдет возврат значения из функции.

$.ajax(), начиная с jQuery версии 1.5,поддерживает интерфейс обещаний(Promise) - советую использовать его.

Я переписал ваш код с использованием обещаний:

```
function test(){
    return $.ajax({
        url: url,
        method: 'GET',
        data: {id : id}
    });
}

$result = test();
$result
.done(function (data) {
    console.log("Success!" + data);
})
.fail(function (e) {
    console.log("Failure!" + e);
});
```